Find subspace $T$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{3} =V \oplus T$
\begin{array}{l} V=\{( a+2b,2a+8b+2c,a+10b+4c) \ |\ a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\}\\ =\{a( 1,2,1) +b( 2,8,10) +c( 0,2,4) \ |\ a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\}\\ =Sp\{( 1,2,1) ,( 2,8,10) ,( 0,2,4)\} \end{array}
Then I proved  $\displaystyle \mathbb{R}^{3} =V+T$.
but got stuck
$\displaystyle V\cap T=\{0\}$
how to prove that?
Thanks a lot!

You don't need to enclose text in dollar signs.

Try $T=Sp (0,0,1)$.

Just take $T=V^\perp$, then the results follow as $\mathbb{R}^3$ is finite dim. (Of course you can choose any inner product.)

@geetha290krm How did you get to this?

Actually, $T=\Bbb R^3$, and therefore it is false that $V\cap T=\{0\}$.
Note that $(1,2,1)=\frac12(2,8,10)-(0,2,4)$. Since, on the other hand, $\{(2,8,10),(0,2,4)\}$ is a linearly independent set, $V=\operatorname{span}(\{(2,8,10),(0,2,4)\})$. So, you can take $T=\operatorname{span}(\{1,0,0\})$, since the set $\{(2,8,10),(0,2,4),(1,0,0)\}$ is linearly independent.

Oh, so I didn't choose T right?
How can I choose it right? How did you got  T=span({1,0,0})?

Yes, your $T$ doesn't work. And, as I wrote in my answer, what I did was to take $T=\operatorname{span}({v})$, where $v$ is a vector such that the set ${(2,8,10),(0,2,4),v}$ is linearly independent. This works because $\dim V=2$ and $\dim\Bbb R^3=3$.

Got it, Although I don't fully understood how you got rid of the (1,2,1) in V, is it because it's a linear combination of the two? if so, what is it based on?

By definition, $V$ is the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by $(1,2,1)$, $(2,8,10)$, and $(0,2,4)$. But, since $(1,2,1)=\frac12(2,8,10)-(0,2,4)$, this is the same thing as saying that $V$ is the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by $(2,8,10)$, and $(0,2,4)$.

First determine the dimension of $V.$ The 3 vectors that generate it, are not linearly independent; if they were, then the dimension would be 3 and $T$ could only be the null space. As it is, try and prove that the dimension of $V$ is only 2 by writing one of the 3 generating vectors as a combination of the other 2. Also, verify that these two remaining vectors are not multiples of each other (so that the dimension of $V$ is more than 1).
Then the complement $T$ should be one-dimensional, i.e., generated by a single vector. Any vector that is linearly independent of the 2 generating vectors of $V$ will do, but one example is the vector product ("cross product") of those two vectors.

Actually we didn't learn dimensions yet then I guess I should solve it without this

Did you learn about the rank of a matrix?

No, only subspaces and addition of them

What did you learn about the specific meaning of the circle around the plus sign?
